# WPF Something wrong with Data grid with checkbox column

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my markup for Datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid"
          FontWeight="Normal" SelectionMode="Extended"
          AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF080101" 
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF0A0101" 
          BorderBrush="#FF245E97" 
          CanUserSortColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="#FF515151"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DiseaseIdColumn" Binding="{Binding DiseaseId}" Header="DiseaseId" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DiseaseNameColumn" Binding="{Binding DiseaseName}" Header="Disease" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SymptomIdColumn" Binding="{Binding SymptomId}" Header="SymptomId" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SymptomNameColumn" Binding="{Binding SymptomName}" Header="Symptom" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DescriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding SymptomDescription}" Header="Description" Width="425" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="StatusIdColumn" Header="Delete"  IsReadOnly="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This Data grid will be loaded by around a hundred entries and since it has a MaxHeight of 250, the datagrid will have a scrollbar inside.

This is the problem, whenever I check a checkbox, and do some event (i.e, click another row without checking a checkbox, clicking a button, any event) and scroll down, the checkbox that I checked is now unchecked, and the check mark now appears in a different row and not only one check, there are several checks now.

Here are the screenshots:

I checked a checkbox

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oeeu.jpg

Then, I click a row (without cheking its box)

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5BVx.jpg

Then, this happened

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U0Cp.jpg

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T7g3.jpg

Comment: The `Checkbox` is not bound to anything so the `DataGrid` has no idea what value to set, and since the `DataGrid` uses `Virtualization` it will only render the amount of rows you can see, that's why it appears to move to another item, when infact it does not, so a solution would be to bind the `IsChecked` value to a property in your model or disable `Virtualization`

Comment: You should have put this in the answer, I would have chosen it as the answer. Thanks!!!